# Fit lowercase text to box model

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I'm currently trying to add to [this](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud) python word cloud library a html export (to the existing image one).

The big problem right now is, that the underlying python image [library](https://python-pillow.org/) is treating text differently. It draws the "box" around a word at the upper edge of the biggest character of the word. So the box is always as tight as possible to the text.

Browser interpret HTML + CSS differently. They don't make the box as tight as possible, but in a way that all possible characters can fit in. So if the word only consists of lower-case characters the browser will still put some space to the top for the case that there could be upper-case characters.

So my question is now how to achieve a similar behavior with such a "tight" box in CSS.

To illustrate better what I mean, here's an image [image]

In the background you see the resulting png file from the python library, and on top of that the HTML+CSS version. The small white boxes mark the beginning of the box in the png. I put a 50% opacity background around the HTML words to show their box model.

My HTML code for this example is:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/html5resetcss/html5reset-1.6.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul style="width:400px; height: 200px; background-image: url(test.png); position: absolute; top:0;left:0;">
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;position: absolute; color: rgb(119, 209, 83); top: 64px; left: 15px; font-size: 102px">hallo</li>
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;transform: rotate(270deg); transform-origin: 50% 90% 0;position: absolute; color: rgb(47, 180, 124); top: 51px; left: 321px; font-size: 73px">ich</li>
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;position: absolute; color: rgb(108, 205, 90); top: 3px; left: 99px; font-size: 61px">test</li>
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;position: absolute; color: rgb(189, 223, 38); top: 142px; left: 114px; font-size: 59px">sie</li>
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;position: absolute; color: rgb(168, 219, 52); top: 37px; left: 50px; font-size: 44px">du</li>
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;position: absolute; color: rgb(31, 161, 135); top: 8px; left: 281px; font-size: 44px">er</li>
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;position: absolute; color: rgb(41, 122, 142); top: 143px; left: 256px; font-size: 44px">es</li>
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;position: absolute; color: rgb(69, 55, 129); top: 149px; left: 17px; font-size: 44px">wir</li>
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;position: absolute; color: rgb(38, 173, 129); top: 34px; left: 241px; font-size: 44px">ihr</li>
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;position: absolute; color: rgb(108, 205, 90); top: 14px; left: 318px; font-size: 41px">und</li>
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;position: absolute; color: rgb(170, 220, 50); top: 1px; left: 2px; font-size: 37px">soll</li>
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;position: absolute; color: rgb(31, 154, 138); top: 167px; left: 227px; font-size: 33px">dann</li>
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;transform: rotate(270deg); transform-origin: 50% 90% 0;position: absolute; color: rgb(67, 62, 133); top: 54px; left: 176px; font-size: 33px">nun</li>
         <li style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5.5em; display: inline; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;transform: rotate(270deg); transform-origin: 50% 90% 0;position: absolute; color: rgb(234, 229, 26); top: 71px; left: 128px; font-size: 33px">tun</li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem can be solved in pure HTML/CSS, as the box is unaware of the actual characters in it — it just reserves height based on properties in the font.

You could either pick apart the font (using something like [opentype.js](https://opentype.js.org/), looking at the height of the characters in your box and setting its height accordingly. A simpler solution would be to draw your text on a canvas and crop the empty space around it, effectively doing what the Python version does. Downside is that your text is now an image (harder to link or select).

Comment: Hm yeah, I suspected that. I'll try to solve it via drawing on a fake HTML/CSS page and then looking afterwards where there's space left for other words. I just hoped there would be a secret but neat CSS trick to achieve what I want :D